# $index in angularjs using ng-form and ng-model

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am using ng-model and I want to add $index to the ng-model but it is not working properly. Anybody can help on where I should place the $index.

thanks

I have updated the full code:-

This is my html code:-

```
    <form name="Bookentry" ng-submit="save()">

        <div  ng-repeat="lists in list.Books | orderBy: ['numB','numB1' ]">

            <ng-form name="item">

                {{$index+1}}

                <input type="checkbox" ng-click="delete(lists._id)">{{lists.numB}} - {{lists.numB1}} - {{lists.bookname}}
                <input type="text" name="Reference" ng-model="Bookentry.item.Reference[$index]" ng-maxlength="8" ng-minlength="1"></input>
                <input type="text" name="Remarks" ng-model="Bookentry.item.Remarks[$index]" ng-maxlength="8" ng-minlength="1"></input>
                <button type="submit">Save</button>
            </ng-form>
        </div>          
    </form>
```

My core.js codes is:-

```
$scope.save = function(){
    $http.post('/api/save',$scope.Bookentry)
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.list = {};
            $scope.list.Books = data;
        })
        .error(function(data){
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
};
```

My app.js is:

```
app.post('/api/save', function(req,res){

  dbBooks.create({
    numB: req.body.numB,
    numB1: req.body.numB1,
    name: req.body.bookname,
    Reference: req.body.Reference,
    remarks: req.body.remarks,
    done: false
  }, function(err,result){
    if (err)
        res.send(err);
    dbBooks.find(function(err,result){
        if (err)
            res.send(err)
        res.json(result)
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: It should work this way can you check if array Bookentry.item.Reference is correct Check this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/YaOg2UrMjlnKXPzVXjlJ?p=preview

Comment: it is not working. I think it is because i use Form and ng-form

Comment: Working example with ngForm http://plnkr.co/edit/YaOg2UrMjlnKXPzVXjlJ?p=preview . Can you create a plunker of your code?

Comment: I think is that there is problem because Bookentry is not an array and I do not know how to make it an array

Comment: Bookentry is not supposed to be an array as per your code, it should be object which has item which again is object and then it contains Reference and remark which are array.

Comment: when i use ng-model="Bookentry.item.Reference[$index]", I am unable to input text in the input box, but when i remove the [$index] i am able to do so

Comment: Could you please update the bookentry object in your question. I want to see its structure.